# How to deploy frontend(Vue or React) + Nginx with kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, frontend, devops

I'm trying to deploy Vue JS app on k8s. The frontend was wrapped into an image with Nginx as a static handler. This configuration working when I access just a service with cluster IP and node port but not working with ingress. Tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

Frontend image

```
FROM node:latest as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx as production-stage
RUN mkdir /client
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vue-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: vue-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: vue-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod: vue-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vue-app
        image: frontend-image
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

here is my service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vue-app-service
spec:
  selector:
      pod: vue-app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
```

and ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-shiny-site.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: vue-app-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Is the pod running ? What happens if you port-forward into the service, does it works as intended?

Comment: Can you post the nginx.conf that you're mapping in? Also, whats in the logs for the ingress controller?  You may have a problem there first off

Comment: If you are using NodePort, then how come servicePort is `80` in the Ingress as it will be some random port, for which you need to write some logic to fetch that port. I have 2 suggestions :
1 - Either change to ClusterIP and choose the service port
2 - Change to fixed NodePort and put that NodePort in Ingress

Comment: Which Ingress Controller are you using ? Are you running this on any cloud platform ? also what do you see as an output to kubectl describe ingress example-ingress.

Comment: This depends on Controller as mentioned above, i.e. here is my working configuration for bare metal / NodePort - https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-deployment/tree/master/k8s_templates